# html.erb doesn't recognize html tags?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

New to RoR, so please don't kill me ;)

Was wondering why does not Rails 3 recognize HTML tags retrieved from database?

For example,

```
         Name   Content                     
         Title  <b>Great</b>    Show    Edit    Destroy
```

I wanted to have Content to be bold and put < b > tag around it, when it retrieves from a database it looks like a plain English.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I got this right, you need to do this:

```
<%= myrecord.content.html_safe %>
```

to get "real" html and not just escaped html code.

Comment: HTML is encoded for security reasons. There could be anything in the database that could break your user experience, create a security flaw or execute malicious code. If you are to use "html_safe" method, you have to make EXTREME care of what can be in the database!

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is unsafe to deliberately output HTML from the DB, you should call `raw` on the content you're trying to print.

```rb
<%= raw @object.my_content %>
```

Comment: Either you trust the content and send it _unsafe_ or you filter the content before saving it into the DB.

Comment: 'filter content' you mean what Rails does by default before sending to DB?

Comment: AFAIK, as of Rails 3.0.0, everything in the view is sanity checked. If you wish to output _real_ HTML, either use `raw` or `@obj.attribute.html_safe`.